Microphone doesn't work mic bar shows activity from system settings
Linux noob here, I can't get my mic to work. Mic shows activity from system sounds like when I play something form yt the bar jumps, before ubuntu I had PopOS and everything worked normally. Also I'm using headphones which use 3,5mm jack splitter for output and input. Also I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Alsamixer playback
alsamixer capture
sound settings
pavucontrol
